# How to solve org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException while fetching the data from DB using spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

**Domain Classes**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "SAMPLE_DATA")
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class Sample implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1719868663566734198L;

    @Id
    private Long Id;
    
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json",name = "person")
    private Person personObj;
    private String sampledata;
    private String createdBy;

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5427425033242474312L;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
}
```

**Repository Class**

```
@Repository
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sample, Long> {
   @Query(value = "select s.personObj,s.sampledata from     Sample s where s.Id=:Id")
List<Sample> findPersonById(Long Id);
}
```

To map to map JSON object types i m using

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version> 
 </dependency>
```

**when I am trying to fetch the list of Sample object I am getting the following exception**

org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type           [java.lang.Object[]] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.domain.Sample] for value '[Person(firstName=abc, lastName=test)]'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.domain.Person] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.domain.Sample]
.........
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.domain.Person] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.domain.Sample]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to select the distinct columns. You must select the Entity:

```
@Repository
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sample, Long> {

   @Query(value = "select s from Sample s where s.Id=:Id")
   List<Sample> findPersonById(Long Id);
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your response. I have missed some of the properties from Sample class.

Comment: What do you mean by missed?

Comment: If i want to retrieve only two columns data including json type

Comment: I don't understand your question. What should be the result of the query? Person class?

Comment: My query is "select s.personObj,s.sampledata from Sample s where s.Id=:Id" and the result of the query is Sample Class

Comment: That's not possible.